# Regex to join fields in a CSV

Tags: windows, linux, regex, csv

I have a CSV with over 2 million records in it with the following format.

```
path;name;extension;size;date;user    
/foo/;difacs;cgi;3,795;18-07-2011;Unix User\pads
/foo/;difacs.cgi;bak;2,622;03-12-2009;Unix User\pads
/foo/test/kzt/netcdfSample/testing/;zzz;;401;27-07-2006;Unix User\kzt
/foo/test/kzt/netcdfSample/vic_netcdf_popup/;a;txt;1,832;17-02-2006;Unix User\kzt
```

I need to join the path, name and extension into one correctly formatted field.

```
path;size;date;user    
/foo/difacs.cgi;3,795;18-07-2011;Unix User\pads
/foo/difacs.cgi;bak;2,622;03-12-2009;Unix User\pads
/foo/test/kzt/netcdfSample/testing/zzz/;401;27-07-2006;Unix User\kzt
/foo/test/kzt/netcdfSample/vic_netcdf_popup/a.txt;1,832;17-02-2006;Unix User\kzt
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which operating system are you on? Which tools to you normally use? What have you tried?

Comment: Windows 7 using TextPad's regex search and replace function but I can just as easily switch over to a linux command line.
I'm new to regex so not really understanding it a whole lot.

Comment: It might be a lot easier to just load this into a spreadsheet and merge the fields there

Comment: I would but excel can't deal with 2 million rows and I'd rather not have to split the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation on slhck's answer which deals properly with an empty extension field (and avoids falsely replacing a dot that might have existed in the second or third field intentionally):

```
sed 's/^\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\)/\1\2/;ta;:a;s/^[^;]\+;;/&/;t;s/;/./' inputfile
```

It's not necessary to use a third capture group. That answer works without it. It's not necessary to escape the dot on the right hand side of the substitute command.

Here's an explanation of my script:

- capture the first two fields, excluding the semicolons that delimit them.
- `ta;:a` - if a successful replacement was made, then branch to label `:a` which immediately follows - this effectively clears the "success" flag
- `s/^[^;]\+;;/&/` - replace a sequence of non-semicolons followed by two semicolons (the concatenated first and second fields followed by an empty third field) with itself - it's a no-op, but it sets the "success" flag.
- `t` - if the last replacement was successful (the third field is empty), skip to the end of processing of the current line (since no label was specified)
- `s/;/./` - if we've gotten to this point (the third field was *not* empty), replace the semicolon with a dot.

Comment: Can you just let me know if you downvoted my answer or not? Trying to retrace a serial downvote incident.

Comment: @slhck: No. I didn't. As you can see from my [profile page](http://superuser.com/users/310/dennis-williamson) I've only cast two downvotes in my almost 3 yrs of activity. I know you're only asking for the purpose of process of elimination.

Comment: That works perfectly. Now I just need to de-construct what you've done and how it works. But you have pulled my bacon out of the fire on this one ;)

Comment: @StefWill: Feel free to ask for clarification if my explanation is lacking.